# How can I get the text by color from a word document with win32com?

Tags: python, ms-word, ms-office, win32com

I have a word document with several tables. In each table there are two colors, black and red.

I'd like to get the text from cells in a word document table by its color. I found a way, but I think it's very inefficient.

The following code gets the text from a word table cell, and prints each word with it's color.

```py
import os, sys
import win32com.client, re

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"../files/tests2.docx")
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 1
doc=word.Documents.Open(path)

for table in doc.Tables:
    f = 2
    c = 2
    wc = table.Cell(f,c).Range.Words.Count
    for i in range(1,wc):
        print table.Cell(f,c).Range.Words(i), table.Cell(f,c).Range.Words(i).Font.Color
```

Do you know any other (better) way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: `xrange(n)` is more efficient than `range(0,n)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to extract highlighted words from a Word document using [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx):

```
#!usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from docx import *
document = opendocx(r'test.docx')
words = document.xpath('//w:r', namespaces=document.nsmap)
WPML_URI = "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}"
tag_rPr = WPML_URI + 'rPr'
tag_highlight = WPML_URI + 'highlight'
tag_val = WPML_URI + 'val'
tag_t = WPML_URI + 't'
for word in words:
    for rPr in word.findall(tag_rPr):
        high=rPr.findall(tag_highlight)
        for hi in high:
            if hi.attrib[tag_val] == 'yellow':
                print word.find(tag_t).text.encode('utf-8').lower()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using win32com because I need to work with both .doc and .docx documents. I will take a look to the library you pointed out.