# how to identify text colors in a word document using python?

Tags: python, fonts, colors, ms-word

I am trying to extract some text from a word document based on their font colors?
I was wondering is there any efficient way of doing so using python packages?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `docx` library! If you're looking for an example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625732/how-can-i-get-the-text-by-color-from-a-word-document-with-win32com?rq=1) might help!

Comment: Thanks. Atucally I've seen this post but I am getting error when using document.xpath:
AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'xpath'