# Extract highlighted text from .docx / .doc file

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

First of all, I need to extract specific words/phrases from large documents (mostly docx and pdf files). So far, we agreed on receiving data as highlighted text since copy-pasting all word tokens in an excel wont be feasible for them. 
While attempting to extract highlighted text, I found this post: [How can I get the text by color from a word document with win32com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625732/how-can-i-get-the-text-by-color-from-a-word-document-with-win32com/14626491#14626491)

In this post Bio-Geek has given a code snippet, which is exactly what I needed, but I am unable to run it, the error is:

NameError: name 'opendocx' is not defined

I expected opendocx to be taken care by - from docx import *

I tried python versions 2.7 and 3.6 and both threw same error.

I tried fetching the XML tags through beautifulsoup, no luck. I am fairly new to parsing docs.
If someone can suggest another way to receive data without adding huge workload to data team, will be highly appreciated.

Here is the code snippet from Bio-Geek which I referred earlier.

```py
from docx import *
document = opendocx(r'test.docx')
words = document.xpath('//w:r', namespaces=document.nsmap)
WPML_URI = "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}"
tag_rPr = WPML_URI + 'rPr'
tag_highlight = WPML_URI + 'highlight'
tag_val = WPML_URI + 'val'
tag_t = WPML_URI + 't'
for word in words:
    for rPr in word.findall(tag_rPr):
        high=rPr.findall(tag_highlight)
        for hi in high:
            if hi.attrib[tag_val] == 'yellow':
                print word.find(tag_t).text.encode('utf-8').lower()
```

NameError: name 'opendocx' is not defined

Comment: Try to double check if the version of the dependency you are installing actually contains those classes/methods. It's not uncommon for python libraries to produce broken installs because of unpinned dependencies

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to use python-docx, you can use the below snippet. If you're only looking for text highlighted in a certain color, you can do a further check on that (see https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Font.highlight_color)

```py
import docx

document = docx.Document("input.docx")

highlights = []
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    highlight = ""
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if run.font.highlight_color:
            highlight += run.text
    if highlight:
        highlights.append(highlight)

for h in highlights:
    print(h)
```

Answer (score 2):

`opendocx()` is no longer part of the latest version of python-docx. And the last version where it was compatible was before `v0.3.0`. You need to use Document to open the file

```
document = Document(docx_file_path)
```

You can read more about it from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-docx/otp6hq4kJ5c/tfQB88Mfx2gJ)

Comment: I have tried this already, but then the error is:  **AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'xpath'**

Comment: @BinitBhagat Because that `xpath` is not valid for document. I would recommend you to go through the documentation https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. It seems you are following some outdated blog which is for old version

Comment: yeah.. I got that. I tried finding substitute to `xpath` but no luck so far. `python-docx` mainly focuses on editing / updating docx rather than parsing.

Comment: @BinitBhagat. Well I have used it in the past and did the same thing what you are trying to achieve. You can contact me on codementor, I can guide you there.